# mysql connection error with hive

Tags: mysql, hive, apache-pig, sqoop, hadoop2

When i am trying to connect mysql remotely(from datanode in hadoop-2.5.1 cluster) with hive it throwing errot:

> ```
> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unable to open a test connection to the given database. JDBC url = jdbc:mysql://192.168.4.43:3306/metastore ? createDatabaseIfNotExist=true, username = root. Terminating connection pool. Original Exception: ------
> java.sql.SQLException: null,  message from server: "Host 'ravi' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server"
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1078)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:975)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1110)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2483)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2516)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2301)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:834)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)  org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:72)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:2372)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:2383)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getDatabase(Hive.java:1139)
> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: null,  message from server: "Host 'ravi' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server"
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1078)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:975)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1110)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2483)sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
> 14/11/17 14:06:53 INFO ql.Driver: </PERFLOG method=task.DDL.Stage-0 start=1416213412561 end=1416213413277 duration=716>
> FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient
> 14/11/17 14:06:53 ERROR ql.Driver: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient
> ```

please if anyone have solution let me know. 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You would have to create new mysql User for ravi from command line like below:

```
CREATE USER 'ravi'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'ravi'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
CREATE USER 'ravi'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'ravi'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Change appropriate values as per your environment and retry your query with hive.

Comment: i am getting this kind of error from mysql:  mysql> CREATE USER 'ravi'@'192.168.4.43' IDENTIFIED BY 'root';
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation CREATE USER failed for 'ravi'@'192.168.4.43'